# How to properly solve "Design For Extension" CheckStyle warning on hashCode and equals

Tags: java

Given:

```all
public class Foo {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        // implementation
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

And

```all
public class Bar extends Foo {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        // different implementation
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // different implementation
    }
}
```

I understand why Checkstyle is giving me the "Design For Extension: Method 'hashCode' is not designed for extension - needs to be abstract, final or empty." The method is neither final, abstract or empty. But how else would I achieve this, and not violate any OO rules or guidelines? For an example of where this would be used:

Foo (for the sake of brevity, I've used the default Object implementation)

```all
public class Foo {

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(final int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        return super.equals(obj);
    }

    private int x;
}
```

```all
public class Bar extends Foo {

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = result * prime + getX();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Bar)) {
            return false;
        }
        final Bar bar = (Bar) obj;
        if (bar.getX() != this.getX()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

```all
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Bar barOne = new Bar();
    barOne.setX(1);
    final Bar barTwo = new Bar();
    barTwo.setX(1);
    final Map<Bar, String> barMap = new HashMap<>();
    barMap.put(barOne, null);
    barMap.put(barTwo, null);
    System.out.println(barMap.size());

    final Foo fooOne = new Foo();
    fooOne.setX(1);
    final Foo fooTwo = new Foo();
    fooTwo.setX(1);
    final Map<Foo, String> fooMap = new HashMap<>();
    fooMap.put(fooOne, null);
    fooMap.put(fooTwo, null);
    System.out.println(fooMap.size());
}
```

Outputs

```
1
2
```

In this situation, using Bar in the map shows that there is only one element in the Map, because when putting the value into the Map, it checks to see if there is an element already with the existing hashCode. In the default Object implementation(Foo), it creates a unique value for all objects created (relatively). The Bar class implementation is based on the x field. When it is put into the map, only one element exists, because the hashCode is the same.

So, is there a way to meet the requirements, while still being able to define a Foo and Bar in the previous example?

Comment: An (old) bug suggests that this behaviour is a bug: ['Design For Extension check should skip toString() ... and maybe hashCode() and equals()](http://sourceforge.net/p/checkstyle/bugs/295/). It's currently still open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid that you have hit a nasty OO trap, that is not limited to Java.

In cases where I want the parent and child to be interchangeable, then I find that the simplist solution is to never override hashcode and equals after they were implemented on my base class (obviously overriding from java.lang.Object is good).  If one does not care about them being interchangeable, then there is no problem.

Failure to follow the hashcode/equals contract nearly always hits an OO trap where it is possible to hit weird bugs when using the objects in hashmaps and sets.  Remember that a class designed for closed extension should be substitable for the class that it extends, otherwise known as the liskov substitution rule.

Full details, with examples are documented by [Joshua Bloch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch) in [item 8 of Effective Java](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=%3Fjoshua+bloch+effective+java+equals+hashcode&source=bl&ots=yZDgMkt-U-&sig=mcF5gDK8mIhTa9x9Aj4b7rqwF2E&hl=en&sa=X&ei=K0QhVP7qNYLm7gbEgoHwCw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%3Fjoshua%20bloch%20effective%20java%20equals%20hashcode&f=false).  The key quote from Joshua is (see bottom of page 38):

> There is no way to extend an instantiable class and add a value component while preserving the equals contract, unless you are willing to forgot the benefits of OO abstraction.

If this sounds too far fetched for you, please remember that Joshua Bloch worked at Sun helping to create Java.  He knows this area very well, and his book has stood the test of time as one of the most 'must read' Java development books out there.

Comment: So, if that's the case, then subclasses would not be able to be more specific than their parent class correct? If Foo is the parent class, and has a field x, and the hashCode method there takes into account the value of x, then all instance of Foo, with the same value of x will have the same hashCode. However, if we have class Bar that extends Foo, with field y, then it's possible that two instances with the same value of x in Foo, and different values of y in Bar, they have the same hashCode, and are considered equal. Which may be against what the developer wants, or in fact wholly wrong.

Comment: @zymus developers break the hashcode/equals contract all of the time; but yes extending a class and then overriding its hashcode to behave differently to its parent creates edge cases where the parent and child will no longer be interchangeable.  A developer may decide that not being interchangeable is fine; however most do it without knowing about the potential issue.

Answer (score 2):

Let's make this problem specific.

1. We have objects `a`, `b`, and `c`.
2. We have `a.equals(b)` and `a.equals(c)`. By contract, we *must also* have `b.equals(c)`.
3. `a` is an instance of `Base`; `b` and `c` are instances of `Derived`.

Now try to define such a `Derived#equals` that the contract is satisfied. You have no choice but to leave it exactly the same as already defined for `Base`.

Note that the converse relatioships must also hold: if `a` is equal to `b`, but not `c`, then `b` must not be equal to `c`, either. In broader terms, `equals` must partition your objects into exactly the same *equality classes* regardless of whether they are considered as instances of `Base` or `Derived`.

Your question is about `hashCode()`, but due to the well-known requirement that `hashCode` must be consistent with `equals`, the same catch applies.

Comment: Is there any way to specify in which context to determine equality? For example, is there any way to determine that (in the context of `Base`) a and b are equal? If the `Base#equals` takes into account a field `x`, and `Derived#equals` take into account a field `y`, is it possible to see if `Base a` and `Derived b` are equivalent based only on the `Base#equals` implementation?

Comment: @zymus remember that the equals contract has to be symmetric, transitive, reflexive and consistent.  What you propose would break its symmetry, and possibly its transitivity.

Comment: @ChrisK How so? Given class `Base` with field `x`, if you have three instances, `a`, `b`, `c`, all with `x = 0` then they would all be equal, even if `b` and `c` are actually instances of `Derived` with their own values for `y`, in the context of `Base` they are all equal.

Comment: @zymus will a.equals(b) give the same result as b.equals(a)?  and if a.equals(b) AND b.equals(c), will a.equals(c) be true?

Comment: @zymus if yes, then I believe that in the proposal that the base class will need to know about the child class; which has its own problems.

Comment: @ChrisK That's what I'm asking; if there is a way to do that. If there is a way, then yes. Calling it in the context of the `Base` class, it could not conceivably know about the child class. But again, it wouldn't matter, because what we are saying is "given that both of these are `Base` objects, are they equal in terms of being `Base` objects". It's like having a class `Child` with a field `firstName`. The scenario would be, "Comparing these two objects, as instances of `Child`, do they share the same first name. If yes, than as far as I'm aware, they are equal. They are both named "Johnny""

Comment: @zymus so long as the child has not added an extra component to the identity check, then that could work.. if it has then no, sorry.  The base class would have to use instanceof checks for each of the kids (yuck).  Joshua Bloch does offer a solution that uses delegation instead of inheritance that you may want to consider.  I strongly recommend reading Joshua Blochs write up on this (item 8 of his book); he goes over this much more clearly than I am here.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this does not answer 'how to fix that' checkstyle warning. Still adding my two cents.
IMO, design for extension, even though stated as Open closed principle would here mean that the hashcode/equals method abides [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Mostly it is achieved through abstraction and as Chris pointed out referring to Joshua Bloch's comment, you cannot add a significant field to a instantiable (non-abstract) class without compromising on the equals contract. 
I think it may not be always worthwhile to aim for perfect abstraction hierarchy. You may have to go with the a solution the does not conform to OCP and LSP. It is a judgement call.